# How to Integrate Result of 2 SQL queries of same Table in a Single Query?

Tags: mysql

I am new to SQL i have just started to learn SQL. I have an Employee table which has 3 columns :

- id  int,
- name varchar(255),
- manager_id int

when manager_id is same as id means an employee will have another employee as manager.

For example:

Employee "AAA" will have "BBB" as his manager if employee record has id of employee "BBB" as manager_id.

How could I write an single SQL query which would give me result of "Employee name" and their corresponding "Manager_name".

Below are the details of Table, Queries tried so far and The expected result.

Employee Table:

```
select * from test.employee;
```

[image]

Query 1:

```
SELECT name as manager_name FROM test.employee  
 where manager_id IN(select id from test.employee)
 group by manager_id;
```

[image]

Query 2:

```
 SELECT name as emp_name FROM test.employee
```

[image]

How could I achieve the combined result of Query 1 and Query 2  i.e as shown below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the same table twice and give it an alias, something like this:

```
SELECT e.name, m.name as manager_name
FROM test.employee e
join test.employee m on e.manager_id = m.id
```

If there's employees where manager doesn't exist, you might want to use `left outer join` instead